# Monitor microphone and save filtered segments

Tags: bash, sox, microphone

I use the following script to monitor my microphone:

```
while true; do
    printf "$(AUDIODEV=hw:2,0 rec -n stat trim 0 1 2>&1 |
        awk 'BEGIN { ORS="" } /^Maximum amplitude/ { print "Max. amplitude: "$3} 
             /^Rough\s+frequency/ { print " Frequency: "$3} 
             /^Maximum\s+delta/ { print " Max. delta: "$3}')\r";
done
```

It records a segment which is 1 second long, extracts values of `Maximum amplitude` and `Rough frequency` from the standard `sox` output and prints them.

Can I save a segment to file if its volume or frequency is greater than a particular threshold? I know that I can save each segment and then analyze it, but there will be too many write operations, which I want to avoid.

Comment: If you save the sample to a file in `/tmp` and mount `/tmp` on a `tmpfs` then the file is in memory, so the write operations are not that important.

Comment: @meuh Thanks for suggestion, but I found a solution in the meanwhile. However I don't know whether it is better than yours. My solution is based on piping the output of 'rec' to 'base64' so that it can be encoded to ASCII and stored in a bash variable. If it is time to analyze the segment's volume and frequency I run 'base --decode' on the variable contents.

Comment: That seems like a very good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution in the meanwhile. It is based on piping the output of `rec` to `base64` so that it can be encoded to ASCII and stored in a bash variable. If it is time to analyze the segment's volume and frequency I run `base --decode` on the variable contents. In the script below only volume is analyzed. If it exceeds the threshold (0.6) `handleExcess` is called and the segment is saved. I also increased the segment length to 5 seconds.

```
handleExcess() {
    echo "$1" | base64 --decode > /tmp/"$2".wav
}

VOLUME="";

while true; do
    AUDIO_DATA="$(AUDIODEV=hw:0,0 rec -c 1 -t wav - trim 0 5 2> /dev/null | base64)";
    declare $(echo "$AUDIO_DATA" | base64 --decode | sox - -n stat 2>&1 | awk 'BEGIN { ORS="" } /^Maximum amplitude/ { print "VOLUME="$3 }');

    if [ $(echo "$VOLUME > 0.6" | bc) == 1 ]; then
        AUDIO_DATA_TMP="$AUDIO_DATA";
        handleExcess "$AUDIO_DATA_TMP" "$VOLUME""_""$(date +%s)" &
    fi
done
```